# Fade a Pseudo Element on scroll - JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pseudo-element

I have a pseudo element I'd like to fade to opacity:0 on scroll.  I can't seem to make head nor tale of how to do it.  I've set up a codepen here. http://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/JWyaKr

Normally I'd use Greensock, but I can't on this project. I also have to use a pseudo element, not an absolutely positioned div. The fade needs to happen after 10px scroll from the top and then come back when the user scrolls back to the top (its part of a nav element)

HTML

```
<div id="mydiv">My Div</div>
```

CSS

```
#mydiv {
    background: red;
    width: 10%;
}

#mydiv:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 10%;
    width: 10%;
    top: 30px;
    background: black;
}
```

Any ideas would be awesome.  I feel as though I'm either about to cry or eat a bucket of fried chicken in frustration.

Emily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a `transition` for `opacity` on the pseudo element, and add a class to the main element on scroll that you use in the selector to change opacity on your pseudo element.

```js
var $mydiv = $('#mydiv');
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
    $mydiv.addClass('fade');
  } else {
    $mydiv.removeClass('fade');
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
}

#mydiv {
  background: red;
  width: 10%;
}

#mydiv:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 10%;
  width: 10%;
  top: 30px;
  background: black;
  transition: opacity .25s;
}

#mydiv.fade:after {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">My Div</div>
```